# reliable way to execute bash unicode code with python on windows?

Tags: python, windows, bash, unicode, createprocess

I have have working base code that will execute commands in bash. But everything crashes on windows when using unicode strings. Here's a test example:

```sh
cd /tmp
cat <<EOF > test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names


def execute_bash(cmd):
    command = ["bash", "-c", cmd]
    p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
              close_fds=ON_POSIX, universal_newlines=False)
    return p.communicate()


print(repr(execute_bash('echo hello')))  ## works fine
print(repr(execute_bash('echo à')))      ## fails
EOF

python test.py
```

I'm expecting to have this output (this works with linux):

```
(b'hello\n', b'')
(b'\xc3\xa0\n', b'')
```

But have:

```
('hello\n', '')
('', "bash: $'echo \\303\\203\\302\\240': command not found\n")
```

So my questions are:

- **why is that** ? and
- **how can I make an implementation of `execute_bash` that would work for any code, on windows** ?

Here are a few more background about what I have already looked into, and what I probably lack to solve this issue:

I'm using `python 3.7` and I'm aware a few issues with windows and encodings that I try to keep out of this sample.
I know that CPython's implementation of `Popen` uses `CreateProcessW(..)` since `python 3` and that we are supposed to be able to send direct unicode command lines.
I'm also aware of `subprocess.list2cmdline(..)` existence that will flatten the args in one unicode string to feed in `CreateProcessW(..)`. I'm kinda aware that on the windows world the parsing of the command line is supposed to be handled to the application... but this is where my knowledge gets limited : which application gets the full command line string ? why does it fails to properly deal with the unicode string ?

Note that executing on `cmd.exe` command line, we have the same issue.

```
T:\>bash -c "echo hello"
hello
T:\>bash -c "echo à"
bash: $'echo \303\240': command not found
```

Side note: `\303\240` is octal for utf-8 encoding of `à`.